# SwiftUI [Presentation] Attempt to present ... on ... whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

After adding `.confirmationDialog` to the "Cancel" Button, I get the following message in the console, when I click on "Discard Changes" Button:

> [Presentation] Attempt to present <SwiftUI.PlatformAlertController: 0x1038c8000> on <*TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView*: 0x104c07850> (from <*TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVVS_22_VariadicView_Children7ElementVS_24NavigationColumnModifier*_: 0x104c1b2b0>) whose view is not in the window hierarchy.

What does it mean? And is this something to worry about, or can I just ignore it? Please help

Here's my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var scrum: DailyScrum
    
    @State private var data = DailyScrum.Data()
    @State private var isPresentingEditView = false
    @State private var isShowingConfirmationDialog = false
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Meeting Info")) {
                NavigationLink(destination: MeetingView()) {
                    Label("Start meeting", systemImage: "timer")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Label("Length", systemImage: "clock")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("\(scrum.lengthInMinutes) minutes")
                }
                .accessibilityElement(children: .combine)
                
                HStack {
                    Label("Theme", systemImage: "paintpalette")
                    Spacer()
                    Text(scrum.theme.name)
                        .padding(4)
                        .foregroundColor(scrum.theme.accentColor)
                        .background(scrum.theme.mainColor)
                        .cornerRadius(4)
                }
                .accessibilityElement(children: .combine)
            }
            
            Section(header: Text("Attendees")) {
                ForEach(scrum.attendees) { attendee in
                    Label(attendee.name, systemImage: "person")
                }
            }
            
            Section("History") {
                Label("No meetings yet", systemImage: "calendar.badge.clock")
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(scrum.title)
        .toolbar {
            Button("Edit") {
                isPresentingEditView = true
                data = scrum.data
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingEditView) {
            NavigationView {
                DetailEditView(data: $data)
                    .navigationTitle(Text("\(scrum.title)"))
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .cancellationAction) {
                            Button("Cancel") {
                                isShowingConfirmationDialog = true
                            }
                            .confirmationDialog(
                                "Are you sure you want to discard your changes?",
                                isPresented: $isShowingConfirmationDialog
                            ) {
                                Button("Discard Changes", role: .destructive) {
                                    isPresentingEditView = false
                                    // Causes: [Presentation] Attempt to present <SwiftUI.PlatformAlertController: 0x1038c8000> on <_TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x104c07850> (from <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVVS_22_VariadicView_Children7ElementVS_24NavigationColumnModifier__: 0x104c1b2b0>) whose view is not in the window hierarchy.
                                }
                                Button("Keep Editing", role: .cancel) {
                                    isShowingConfirmationDialog = false
                                }
                            } message: {
                                Text("Are you sure you want to discard your changes?")
                            }

                        }
                        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .confirmationAction) {
                            Button("Done") {
                                isPresentingEditView = false
                                scrum.update(from: data)
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That View is getting too large, I would make a new View for the cancel button and @ State isShowingConfirmationDialog  and pass in a binding to $isPresentingEditView

Comment: I suspect that the problem is that the view contents aren't part of a NavigationView. If you put the entire contents inside a NavigationView it'll probably work. I just encountered this when trying to raise a sheet from a sheet that didn't have a NavigationView. Interestingly, it failed on iOS 15 but not later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose it's because by confirming the cancel you dismiss both the `.confirmationDialog` and the parent `.sheet`. I believe it doesn't hurt, but you can get rid of it like this:

```
            Button("Discard Changes", role: .destructive) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    isPresentingEditView = false
                }
            }
```

..and put it here:

```
    .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingEditView) {
        NavigationView {
            Text("DetailEditView(data: $data)")
                .navigationTitle(Text("(scrum.title)"))
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .cancellationAction) {
                        Button("Cancel") {
                            isShowingConfirmationDialog = true
                        }
                        
                    }
                    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .confirmationAction) {
                        Button("Done") {
                            isPresentingEditView = false
//                          scrum.update(from: data)
                        }
                    }
                }
                // vvv Here
                .confirmationDialog(
                    "Are you sure you want to discard your changes?",
                    isPresented: $isShowingConfirmationDialog
                ) {
                    Button("Discard Changes", role: .destructive) {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            isPresentingEditView = false
                        }
                    }
                    Button("Keep Editing", role: .cancel) {
                        isShowingConfirmationDialog = false
                    }
                } message: {
                    Text("Are you sure you want to discard your changes?")
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.
But unfortunately this message still appears, even after making both changes:
`DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                        isShowingConfirmationDialog = false
                                        isPresentingEditView = false
                                    }`

Comment: ...  oh, I forgot: I also moved the `.confirmationDialog` out of the `.toolbar` to the level of `NavigationView`

Comment: Could you please explain where exactly did you move `.confirmationDialog` ?
Because when I try to move it somewhere else (anywhere), it causes bugs.

Comment: Unfortunately, it causes me a bug (see here): https://media.giphy.com/media/4JN5dhDLZFiqZKzPoW/giphy.gif

Comment: I see ... then move it back to the button.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think this message from the console `[Presentation] Attempt to present ... on ... whose view is not in the window hierarchy.`  may cause some troubles in the future, when I add more features? Or is it relatively safe to ignore it? Or is it maybe something that ought to be fixed by Apple?

Comment: I'd say its quite safe to ignore it.

Comment: It is most definitely not safe to ignore it and it will absolutely cause issues. Try creating an alert. It won't work. I'm having this exact same issue and have yet to find a solution.

Comment: @kittonian, it is causing issues for me the same way for you. I try to create an alert and is not showing. Did you find any solution?